# If $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $f'\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ does that implies $lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Here $f$ is absolutely continuous on each $[-c,c]$ for $c>0$ and f is $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $f'\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ does that implies $f\in C^0(\mathbb{R})$.
I see somewhere...
$(|f|^2)'=f'\bar{f}+f\bar{f}'$ then we have to use cauchy's inequality. But that will give $\int{|f|^2}'<\infty$. But will not implies $lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g=f^{2}$. Then $g$ and $g'$ are integrable. Integrability of $g'$ and FCT show that $g$ is uniformly continuous. But $g$ uniformly continuous and integrable implies that $g(x) \to 0$ as $ x\to \pm \infty$: See [If $f$ is uniformly continuous and integrable, then $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)=0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2799148/if-f-is-uniformly-continuous-and-integrable-then-lim-x-to-infty-fx-0)

[I have used the fact that $\int_E g'(t)dt \to 0$ as $m(E) \to 0$. ($m$ is Lebsegue measure). This gives uniform continuity of $g$].

Comment: I get everything except the fact you have used $\int_E g(t)dt \to 0$ as $m(E) \to 0$. Does it implies uniform continuity. Can you elaborate.

Comment: @BiplabDas There was a typo. I hope it clears your doubt now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more direct proof: Consider $g(x) = f^2(x)$. Then both $g(x)$ and $g'(x) = 2f'(x)f(x)$ are integrable. Now, for any $x < y$,

$$ |g(y) - g(x)|
\leq \int_{x}^{y} |g'(t)| \, \mathrm{d}t
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} |g'(t)| \mathbf{1}_{[x,y]}(t) \, \mathrm{d}t
\xrightarrow{x,y\to\infty} 0 $$

by the dominated convergence theorem. So by the Cauchy criterion, $g(x) = f(x)^2$ converges as $x \to \infty$. Then by the integrability of $g$, the limit must be zero. This is then enough to show that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.